# How to put the largest element in an array at the end and the least at the start from user input?

Tags: java, arrays, input, computer-science, swap

I have extracted the largest and smallest element in an array. I'm trying to figure out how to swap the largest element for the last element in the array and the smallest element for the first number in the array but it's not working for me. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SmallestLargest
{
    public static void main (String []args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int[] array1 = new int [input.nextInt()];

        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
        {
            array1[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        int max = array1[0];
        int least = array1[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
        {
            if(max < array1[i])
            {
                max = array1[i];
            }
            else if(least > array1[i])
            {
                least = array1[i];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
        {
            int x = array1[0];
            array1[0] = max;
            array1[array1.length-1] = x;
            System.out.print(array1[i] + " ");
        }

            input.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need, you have to keep track of the index where the max/min value is located.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int[] array1 = new int[input.nextInt()];
            int maxIndex = -1;
            int minIndex = -1;


            for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
                array1[i] = input.nextInt();
            }
            int max = array1[0];
            int least = array1[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
                if (max < array1[i]) {
                    max = array1[i];
                    maxIndex = i;
                } else if (least > array1[i]) {
                    least = array1[i];
                    minIndex = i;
                }
            }

            int temp = array1[0];
            array1[0] = max;
            array1[maxIndex] = temp;

            temp = array1[array1.length - 1];
            array1[array1.length - 1] = least;
            array1[minIndex] = temp;

            for(int a: array1){
                System.out.println(a);
            }
            input.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second for loop and just do

```
array1[0] = max;
array1[array1.length-1] = least;
```